# Mechanize (Ruby gem) not recognizing a form from a saved HTML file, but it recognizes the form when accessing the actual website?

Tags: ruby, rspec, web-scraping, tdd, mechanize

I'm trying to write Rspec tests for my Mechanize agent.

My agent is supposed to go to a website, log into the form, then scrape some data off the website. I also downloaded FakeWeb to stub the HTTP requests, and make my tests faster.

Here is my account_spec.spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Account do
  before(:each) { @account = Account.new('bob', '1234') }

  describe '#login' do
    before(:each) do
      home_page = File.read('spec/html/home_page.html')
      login_page = File.read('spec/html/login_page.html')

      FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, 
        "https://www.example.com/",
        body: home_page,
        status: ["200", "Success"],
        content_type: "text/html")

      FakeWeb.register_uri(:get,
        "https://www.example.com/account/login",
        body: login_page,
        status: ["200", "Success"],
        content_type: "text/html")

      @web_crawler = Mechanize.new
      @home_page = @web_crawler.get("https://www.example.com/")
      @login_page = @web_crawler.get("https://www.example.com/account/login")
    end # -- before :each

    it 'finds the login form' do
      login_form = @login_page.form_with(:class => "form login")
      puts login_form.class   # ==> nil:NilClass
    end
  end # -- #login

end # -- Account
```

However, when I comment out the FakeWeb uri for `example/account/login` (it then accesses the real server), it actually returns the correct form. Basically, if I am searching for the form in my locally saved HTML file, Mechanize can not find it, but if I check the actual website, it does find it. I would like to know if there is a way around this, and why this happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did the downloaded `login_page.html` file come from? The right way to do this is usually to use the excellent [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to do all the page recording and replaying for you.

Comment: @Dave It was the login page from the website i'm accessing.  I downloaded the source code

Comment: You don't need FakeWeb for this, just use the `Mechanize::Page` constructor

Comment: @Hunter don't download it yourself, use VCR (as I said earlier) which will take care of all that.